# Good examples of Android projects covered by tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, functional-testing

Could you point some good examples of Android projects that have unit testing in action?

It would be great to learn by example from those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the android sources. You can find them on https://android.googlesource.com/.

To be a bit more precise take a look at the Calculator app for example. 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calculator.git

You can see the test directory. I guess that is what you meant.

I hope that this is what you were looking for.

Comment: What I'm looking for is actually fully functional project. Calculator application is very simple one. Aim of this question is to find apps that have some complex logic, use preferences, networking etc. and see how those things are actually tested using both functional and unit tests.

Comment: Well I thought of this link as a resource for that. The calculator app is simple I know it was just an example. They have more applications in that repository like the Email application http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=tree